# Making a visual smooth flowing search bar, ASP.NET C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, search

I am trying to make a search bar with a few feilds. Right now the code is as follows:

```
        <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" Height="25px">
            <asp:ListItem>Database</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Engine</asp:ListItem>
            <asp:ListItem>Pool</asp:ListItem>
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" Height="25px" />
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Height="25px"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server">LinkButton</asp:LinkButton>
```

Right now it looks like crap and doesnt flow at all, I was wondering how I would go about making a better visual looking search bar with all the required feilds.  Thanks.

Example: digg.com has images in there search bar.

EDIT: Basically I want to code this image: http://o.imm.io/qlQ.png

Comment: Care to define what you intend by 'flow'? Visually? Usability? what?

Comment: Edited question, but I ment visually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest lesson I've learned is if you have a small amount of space and some options the user has to choose (*and understand*) don't use standard HTML controls.  Design a real solution opposed to using the annoying HTML elements.

One main issues in building the search area is that the dropdownlist is not very style-able.  Try building in the options that they can choose.  You only have three options to pick from a radiobutton list would work better as the user would see all the options.  You can then apply a filter onto the list and make it an image based toggle option list.

see the first example here for other options (Interface elements on demand) :
http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/01/12/10-useful-web-application-interface-techniques/

[image]
<sub>(source: [smashingmagazine.com](http://media.smashingmagazine.com/cdn_smash/images/web-applications-interface-techniques/kontain_search.png))</sub>